# How do I make my TextBox pass a Date value in MVC 3?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, date, textbox

When I submit the data, even though I type in 3/15/2012, the model is always populated with 1/1/0001. What am I missing?

```
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EventDate, "Date of Event")<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m =>  m.EventDate)
</p>
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Event", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <input id="create" type="submit" value="Submit New Event" />
    }
</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the textbox inside the form.
Otherwise, it never gets sent to the server.